# how to get max number of redirects on Chrome? (before ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS )

Tags: google-chrome, redirection, chromium

like on Firefox one would go to about:config and look up the `network.http.redirection-limit` setting, what is the Chrome equivalent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's 20, and it's actually [specification-defined](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#http-redirect-fetch), so there is no configuration option. I found it in Chromium's source code at [net/url_request/url_request.h](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/refs/heads/main/net/url_request/url_request.h):

```cpp
// Max number of http redirects to follow. The Fetch spec says: "If
// request's redirect count is twenty, return a network error."
// https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#http-redirect-fetch
static constexpr int kMaxRedirects = 20;
```